# [RN][IOS]Is it possible to use react native RCTLinking in conjonction with RNFirebase dynamic links?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I am currently handling ios universal links through the RCTLinking API. For some reasons, I need to work with Firebase dynamic links and I am wondering if it is possible to use both in my app.
My issue is that the implementation in :

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

and

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler`

that seems incompatible as I would need to return both RCTLinkingManager and RNFirebaseLinks

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to answering this question, but the currently proposed answer will not work. It will fail to open actions from Firebase In-App Messaging since the returned `NO` from `RNFirebaseLinks` will get overwritten by `RCTLinkingManager` with `YES` for the restoration handler.

If you come across this, try the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
   BOOL handledLink = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];

  if (!handledLink) {
      handledLink = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }
  return handledLink;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
  
  BOOL handleRestore = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  
  if (!handleRestore) {
    handleRestore = [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  }
  return handleRestore;
}
```

My current set up and need for this is `react-navigation` v3 and `react-native-firebase` v5

Comment: I'm confused by your `restorationHandler` logic. Surely `handleRestore` should only be reassigned if `handleRestore` is `null`/`false`? (So that `RCTLinkingManager` can handle things.) At the moment it's only being reassigned if `RNFirebaseLinks` returns `YES`/`true`.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a typo. It should be `if (!handledRestore) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like the code below inside your `restorationHandler` function:

```
BOOL handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
if (!handled) {
    handled = [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                           restorationHandler:restorationHandler];

}
return handled;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  if (url == nil) return false;
  BOOL handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance]
                  application:application
                  openURL:url
                  options:options
                  ] || [RCTLinkingManager
                        application:application
                        openURL:url
                        options:options
                        ];
  return handled;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
  BOOL handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance]
                   application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                   restorationHandler:restorationHandler
                   ] || [RCTLinkingManager
                         application:application
                         continueUserActivity:userActivity
                         restorationHandler:restorationHandler
                         ];
   return handled;
}
```

react-native-firebase: 5.5.6, react-navigation 3.X
Not controlling the url to nil was resulting to a crash when starting the app.